# R: Automatic Library Loading at Session Start

Tags: javascript, r, debugging

Whenever I start R, two packages namely `simsem` package and `lavaan` get loaded automatically.

I also tried to update packages, some of which went through, but the `sp` package did not get updated, with the error, that

> `sp` package is in use (Restart R)

I restart and try to update, but get the same error. So what to do?

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to one of two things:

1. Either you have an `.Rprofile` file in one of R's search directories that is getting loaded up when R starts, and one of those startup scripts contains the library load instructions. You can figure out where R looks for `.Rprofile` and `Rprofile.site` scripts [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html).
2. The other possibility is that you loaded the packages at some point, and now they are part of your `.Rdata` file. Again, check to see if there is an `.Rdata` file that is in R's startup directory, and delete it.

Secondly, to detach a package that you already have attached, you can do (in this example, I will try to detach the `RMySQL` package):

```
detach(name = "package:RMySQL", unload = TRUE)
```

and then try to install it.

Comment: @imrankhan You don't appear to have -- you have to click on the check mark below the upvote/downvote buttons.